# Behaviour of the following function

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

The behaviour os a variable x over time is described by $$\frac {dx} {dt} = x^2 - x$$ where t is the variable denoting time. 
Suppose x is negative initially. What happens to x overtime?

What would this function look like on a graph?

*Context from comment:* My problem was that I couldn't understand what the function would look like on a graph. (which would help me answer my homework) I started by normally finding the critical points, which came out to be $0$ and $1$. Then I double differentiated it to find the maxima and minima. But then I realized that the variable here is $t$ (rather than $x$), which makes me think that the value of $dx/dt$ would depend only on the initial $x$ (and not the $t$). I can't really graph this function in my brain though, and could really use some help!

Comment: Hi Dexter, Maths SE is not a place for solving your homework problems. Rather, it's a place to get help in understanding and reasoning. For this, why don't you start by telling us what you have tried, or what you are unsure about?

Comment: Hey! sorry it was a pretty long question, my problem was that I couldn't understand what the function would look like on a graph. (which would help me answer my homework)

I started by normally finding the critical points, which came out to be 0 and 1. Then I double differentiated it to find the maxima and minima. But then I realized that the variable here is t (rather than x), which makes me think that the value of $dx/dt$ would depend only on the initial x (and not the t). I can't really graph this function in my brain though, and could really use some help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can gain information about the behaviour of the equation even before solving it.

Here we have two functions: $f(y) = y^2-y$ and $x(t)$ defined such that $ \dot x = f(x)$, and $x(0) <0$ (where we use $\dot x = \frac{dx}{dt}$ for shorthand). The question asks for the behaviour of $x$ as time increases. You can learn about that by looking at the sign of $\dot x$ which is equal to the sign of $f(x)$.

$f(x) = 0$ for $x=0$ or $x=+1$, so $f$ is +ve on $(-∞,0) ~~\cap~~ (1,+∞)$ and negative on $(0,1)$. So if $x$ starts of as -ve, you see that $\dot x$ will be positive. As $x$ increases, $\dot x$ will change accordingly.

Can you continue from here?

Answer (score 1):

Just rewrite $$\frac {dx} {dt} = x^2 - x$$ as $$\frac {dt} {dx} =\frac 1{ x^2 - x}=\frac{1}{x-1}-\frac{1}{x}$$ and integrate to get $$t+C=\log\big(\frac {x-1} x \big)$$ Extract $x$ from the equation as a function of $t$.

I am sure that you can take from here.

Comment: Thanks! The question I'm solving asks for the rate of change of x as time increases. Wouldn't it be impossible for x to lie between 0 and 1 here?